# Why does pthread_exit(0) hangs the program?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-exit

Running the following C code causes the program to hang, and does not respond to signals (including CTRL-C).

```
int main()
{
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why?

The behaviour is normal when other threads have been created and are running, but I would like to know if I always have to check that before using pthread_exit(0).

EDIT:
This is the complete code that hangs. However, I was building with glib (-lglib-2.0). Using simply cc -o foo foo.c works as expected.

Comment: Hang?  You terminated it!  Your process had just the one thread - the one created by the loader, and you terminated it:(

Comment: Is this the *complete* code (that hangs)? Then what are the *other threads* you talk about?

Comment: Can't reproduce here, with or without `-lglib-2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire use case is described in the *notes* of the [pthread_exit man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html).
In your case, as you correctly edited your OP, glib started another thread. You exited the main thread and the other thread kept running. You labeled this as a hang.
In general, if you want to exit the application in full, just use `exit` or return from `main()`.

Only when you need additional magic (rarely) like detached threads, use `pthread_exit()` on the main thread.

Comment: I don't think the man page says anything related to the behaviour described by OP.  I can't reproduce the behaviour with glib. Why would glib start another thread?